# Bases and dimensions of two spans

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $$U=\operatorname{span}\{(1,1,0,-1),(1,2,3,0),(2,3,3,-1)\}$$ and $$ W=\operatorname{span}\{(1,2,2,-2),(2,3,2,-3),(1,3,4,-3)\}$$

I am supposed to find basis and dimensions for $U+W$ and $U\cap W$.  I know how to find a basis for a set of vectors (i.e., the basis for $U$ is $(1,1,0,-1),(1,2,3,0)$), but I do not know how to find $U+W$ and $U\cap W$.

Also, is the dimension for the basis of $U$ 2?  If I recall correctly, the dimension is equal to the number of vectors in the basis.

Comment: You're right that the dimension equals the number of vectors in a basis (there are lots of different possible bases, but they all have the same number of vectors). Since $U$ is the set of all linear combinations of the three given vectors and $W$ is the set of all linear combinations of its three vectors, then $U+W$ is the set of all linear combinations of the six vectors, right? As for $U\cap W$, I think that's more complicated. Someone might have a better idea, but I suggest writing both spaces as null spaces of matrices, then append the matrices together.

Comment: So, is $U+W$ just the span(all six vectors)?

Comment: To your last comment, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You can easily prove that $U=\big\langle \underbrace{(1,1,0,-1)}_{u_1},\underbrace{(1,2,3,0)}_{u_2}\big\rangle$ and $W= \big \langle \underbrace{(1,2,2,-2)}_{w_1},\underbrace{(1,3,4,-3)}_{w_2}\big \rangle$.

If you want to find $U + W$, you have to check if all these above ($4$) vectors are linearly independent, which they are not. You can prove that only $3$ of them are linearly independent, which  can span $U+W$.

Now, if I'd want to find $U \cap W $, I would follow this *safe* way:

**First way:**

Let $\vec x \in U\cap W\implies \vec x \in U \text { AND }\vec x \in W$.

That means:

$\vec x= k\cdot ( 1,1,0,-1) + \lambda \cdot (1,2,3,0)$

$\vec x =\mu \cdot ( 1,2,2,-2) + \nu\cdot (1,3,-4,3)$, where $k,\lambda, \mu, \nu \in \mathbb R$.

So, you need to solve a $4\times 4 $ linear system with 4 variables: $k,\lambda, \mu,\nu \in \mathbb R$.

The only solution to the above system is $(k,\lambda,\mu,\nu)=(0,0,0,0)$.

That means $U\cap W= \{(0,0,0,0)\}$.

**Second way:**

Since $u_1, u_2,w_1$ are linearly independent and $u_1,u_2,w_2$ are linearly independent as well, that means that no linear combination of $u_1, u_2$ can be written as linear combination of $w_1, w_2$ (*but one specific case*).

This means that there are no $k,\lambda,\mu, \nu \in \mathbb R$ and **not all zero** such that:

$k\cdot u_1 + \lambda \cdot u_2=\mu \cdot w_1 + \nu\cdot w_2$.

The only case this equation is true is when $k=\lambda=\mu=\nu=0$!

*Note*: Practically, this means that $u_1,u_2,w_1,w_2$ are linearly independent!

Comment: I have already found $U and W$, except I got $(1,2,2,-2),(2,3,2,-3)$ for the basis of $W$.  These are linearly dependent.  However, if I choose ${(1,2,2,-2),(2,3,2,-3),(1,2,3,0)}$, they are linearly independent. Does that mean that that set forms a basis?  Also, finding $U \bigcap W$ is still something that confuses me.

Comment: You probably mean that $ (1,2,2,-2) , (2,3,2,-3)$ are linearly independent. Yeap, this set of  the $3$  vectors you mention is a basis of $U+W$.

Comment: When I set $a\cdot ( 1,1,0,-1) + b \cdot (1,2,3,0) -c \cdot ( 1,2,2,-2) -d \cdot (1,3,-4,3) = 0$.  When I set $d=1$ and solve, I get $a=1,b=0,c=-1$.  The set of vectors that I get are linearly dependent.

Comment: I think I just got it.  This gives me $U \cap V$, then I can find the basis of those vectors. i.e. the basis is $(1,1,0,-1),(1,2,2,-2)$.

Comment: @Confused_Engineer A little more information.